# Example of a function $s\colon U\to \coprod_{P\in U} R_P$ in the structure sheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Example of a function $s\colon U\to \coprod_{P\in U} R_P$ in the structure sheaf

I would like to see how the function actually works with an example.

I tried to make one, but I am not sure if it makes sense.

The function $s$ seems to take values prime ideals in $U$ and give us something in the localization.

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$, then $\mathrm{spec}R = \{ \langle x-c \rangle, c\in \mathbb{C}  \}$.

Let's take the prime ideal $P=\langle x-5\rangle$, the localization is $R_{P}=\{f/g: f,g\in R, g\notin P\}$

then $s$ is something like, for all $P\in U$, $s(P)=\frac{5}{x^2+3}\in R_P$ ?

Comment: You should specify what $U$ is in this case, and I also want to point out that your expression for $\operatorname{Spec} R$ as a set is not quite right. In particular, what you've written is missing one important point.

Comment: @Daniel is missing the zero point, but why is that important ? We can take as $U=\{\langle x-c\rangle : |c|>4\}$, for example, I don't know. $s(P)$ is correct ? Does it make any sense ?

Comment: Although $U$ is not open in the Zariski topology, your expression for $s(P)$ does make sense and is the way most of these sections look. The point corresponding to the ideal $(0)$ is in all nonempty open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x]$ since this is the unique minimal prime ideal in this ring.